# How to send send an image inside html email using swiftmailer?

Tags: 8, emails

in my Drupal 8 installation I'm using [mailsystem module](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsystem) in combination with [swiftmailer](https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer) module. Everything works fine so far, my swiftmailer twig template inside the templates folder of my custom theme is recognized and works as it should in general.

**Problem:**

When I want to embed a logo inside my template (as inline image), the image can't be loaded. It renders the template and shows a broken image placeholder. I used the code mentioned in [readme.txt](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/swiftmailer/-/blob/8.x-2.x/README.txt) (see point 3.2.2) of swiftmailer module:

```
<img src="image:/themes/MYTHEME/logo.png">
```

Same error when I use

```
<img src="image:{{ base_url }}/themes/MYTHEME/logo.png">
```

Logo path is generally working, use the same for my theme in general.

The image is embedded also inside the email (using MailHog to check it):

```
Content-Type: image/png; name=logo.png

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Content-ID: <f8a965e25fc041c5af9318b9d71cd3d1@mysite.site>

Content-Disposition: inline; filename=logo.png

.... image code following ....
```

How can I get my logo image inside my email correctly?
Would like to avoid simply setting a linked image it to my webserver if possible,to minimize webserver traffic.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to generate the base path for absolute links by using this twig filter in my template file:

`{{ base_url ~ directory }}`

There is more detail on the swiftmailer issue page here:
https://www.drupal.org/project/swiftmailer/issues/2809359

Answer (score 1):

The trailing slash was not added to the preprocess function so you need to do something like this:

```
<img src="{{ base_url ~ '/' ~ directory }}/img/mail-logo.png" />
```